# What is Inversion of Control?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic, inversion-of-control, terminology

Inversion of Control (IoC) can be quite confusing when it is first encountered.

1. What is it?
2. Which problem does it solve?
3. When is it appropriate to use and when not?

Comment: The problem with most of these answers is the terminology used.  What's a container?  Inversion?  Dependency?  Explain it in layman terms without the big words.

Comment: See also on Programmers.SE:  [Why is Inversion of Control named that way?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/205681/why-is-inversion-of-control-named-that-way)

Comment: It is Dependency Injection (DI) - see Martin Fowlers' descrition here: http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#InversionOfControl

Comment: Best way to understand IOC is to hear Martin Fowler and Uncle BOB...just type IOC with the names mentioned

Comment: Inversion of Control = Dependency (state) Injection + Continuation (function) Injection + Thread Injection .   More details here:  https://dzone.com/articles/inversion-of-coupling-control

Answer (score 1998, accepted):

The **`Inversion-of-Control` (IoC)** pattern, is about providing *any kind* of `callback`, which "implements" and/or controls reaction, instead of acting ourselves directly (in other words, inversion and/or redirecting control to the external handler/controller).
The **`Dependency-Injection` (DI)** pattern is a more specific version of IoC pattern, and is all about removing dependencies from your code.

> Every `DI` implementation can be considered `IoC`, but one should not call it `IoC`, because implementing Dependency-Injection is harder than callback (Don't lower your product's worth by using the general term "IoC" instead).

For DI example, say your application has a text-editor component, and you want to provide spell checking. Your standard code would look something like this:

```cs
public class TextEditor {

    private SpellChecker checker;

    public TextEditor() {
        this.checker = new SpellChecker();
    }
}
```

What we've done here creates a dependency between the `TextEditor` and the `SpellChecker`.
In an IoC scenario we would instead do something like this:

```cs
public class TextEditor {

    private IocSpellChecker checker;

    public TextEditor(IocSpellChecker checker) {
        this.checker = checker;
    }
}
```

In the first code example we are instantiating `SpellChecker` (`this.checker = new SpellChecker();`), which means the `TextEditor` class directly depends on the `SpellChecker` class.

In the second code example we are creating an abstraction by having the `SpellChecker` dependency class in `TextEditor`'s constructor signature (not initializing dependency in class). This allows us to call the dependency then pass it to the TextEditor class like so:

```cs
SpellChecker sc = new SpellChecker(); // dependency
TextEditor textEditor = new TextEditor(sc);
```

Now the client creating the `TextEditor` class has control over which `SpellChecker` implementation to use because we're injecting the dependency into the `TextEditor` signature.

---

**Note** that just like IoC being the base of many other patterns, above sample is only one of many Dependency-Injection kinds, for example:

- Constructor Injection.

  > Where an instance of `IocSpellChecker` would be passed to constructor, either automatically or similar to above manually.
- Setter Injection.

  > Where an instance of `IocSpellChecker` would be passed through setter-method or `public` property.
- Service-lookup and/or Service-locator

  > Where `TextEditor` would ask a known provider for a globally-used-instance (service) of `IocSpellChecker` type (and that maybe without storing said instance, and instead, asking the provider again and again).

Comment: Good clear example. However, suppose rather than requiring the ISpellChecker interface be passed to the object's constructor, we exposed it as a settable property (or SetSpellChecker method). Would this still constitute IoC?

Comment: chainguy1337 - yes it would. Using setters like that is called setter injection as opposed to constructor injection (both dependency injection techniques). IoC is a fairly generic pattern, but dependency injection acheives IoC

Comment: So, this answer only shows a *way* of achieving IoC rather than explaining the concept, is that right?

Comment: The original dependency graph looks like (main -> TextEditor -> SpellChecker), but in the second code snippet, it looks like (main -> TextEditor, main -> SpellChecker). The dependency from TextEditor to SpellChecker has been broken, which is useful, so I can see that this is an example of dependency injection. However, the thread of control still starts with main, which invokes code in the texteditor. So I'm unclear why this would an example of 'inversion of control'.

Comment: The example you gave is not of IOC, it is Dependency Injection example.

Comment: @urini I am confused.. from this line `public TextEditor(ISpellChecker checker)` isn't `TextEditor` again depending upon `ISpellChecker` ??

Comment: ISpellChecker is an interface, not a defined class. Therefore any class implementing that interface can be 'injected' into TextEditor. Whoever creates TextEditor can determine what implementation of ISpellChecker it uses. And this answer describes Dependency Injection, nothing to do with IoC.

Comment: This is good, but I think it's worst extending why it is useful to reduce the dependencies. For example, what if you wanted a French Spellchecker and a Spanish Spellchecker. Add to the this to the example.

Comment: what about 3rd question?( When is it appropriate and when not?)

Comment: @Rogério Interestingly, even [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) defines IoC exactly the same as this answer, rather than the way Fowler does.  Perhaps it is time to declare Fowler's original definition as archaic?  Either way, I will strictly use the term "DI" from now on, since I don't often discuss IoC in the way Fowler has originally defined it.

Comment: @DanLing I don't see where that Wikipedia entry disagrees with Fowler's articles; compare with [Fowler's own article describing IoC](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html). It disagrees with this answer, though. My take on this IoC x DI confusion is as follows: 1) late 80's, various authors (Fowler not included) defined IoC, with no DI then; 2) early 2000's, Rod Johnson (creator of Spring Framework) decided to (mis-)use the term "IoC" for the injection of dependencies by the framework; 3) early 2004, Martin Fowler coined "DI" as a proper name for the new concept.

Comment: @Imad Alazani: The flow of control has been "inverted" by Dependency Injection (DI)

Comment: @devios I know I'm a little late to the party on this one, but I'd advise against using setter injection for a class which requires some dependency before operation. I find it good practice to ensure that once an object has been constructed, it's completely usable. Constructor injection is a preferred method until your class needs a lot of parameters, at which point you should consider a builder pattern.

Comment: you said : ".....are all about removing dependencies"
But then you said : "What we've done here is create a dependency" - i dont get it if its for removing dependencies why do we add them ?

Comment: @Rogeiro, From what ive understood "IoC" is simply a generic pattern used for removal of dependencies from application. Provided answare is only presenting one solution called "Dependency Injection pattern" but there are other possibilities that achive similar outcome in different ways such as Service Locator. Which for me to be honest is only a wrapper for 'dependency injection' factory... ?

Comment: The term is related to but different from the dependency inversion principle, which concerns itself with decoupling dependencies between high-level and low-level layers through shared abstractions

Comment: It's more of a Dependency Inversion principle example.

Comment: I guess this is interface `ISpellChecker` . but we normally don't provide interface for the Service and Controller classes. Then why do we autowire service and controller(why not create the object of service using `new` ) ?

Comment: I think it's wrong to say that it's about "removing dependencies" . If anything, it's about "making dependencies explicit"

Comment: Maybe this example has some IoC inside it, but it is more an example of dependency injection. It does not shows how the operation is delegated to the checker. This answer is misleadinf and incomplete and it's contributing to increase the confusion that already exists around the difference between IoC and Dependency injection. Someone should moderate this

Comment: OK, there are a lot of posts above this, but I think the fundamental question needs to be (for a yes or a no answer), DO WE WANT THE DEVELOPER OR THE PROCESSOR HAVING TO INJECT A SPELL-CHECKER?  We have traded off one feature (the text editor has a spell-checker) with another (you need to know that you need to inject a spell-checker).  And isn't the ability to SWITCH spell-checkers an endemic text-editor feature?  But here it's already dependent.  Face it, many of these concepts simply represent moving around fundamentally atomic concepts from one place to another..

Comment: I recommend the author to update the answer as people are clearly getting confuse about the relationship of Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control, I liked very much the simple and no framework example. I suggest to give an example of Service Locator as well.

Comment: This is not an example of IOC, It's an example of DI, Watch out below example

Comment: Doing this is all well and good when you have the one type (SpellChecker) but what happens when you have 7 different types? Will the constructor not get a bit out of hand then?

Comment: This is super misleading. I have no idea how this answer is coming on top. This is simple DI

Comment: This is only Dependency Injection, which contributes only 1/5 of the solution towards Inversion of Control.  More details:  https://dzone.com/articles/inversion-of-coupling-control  Inversion of Control = Dependency (state) Injection + Continuation (function) Injection + Thread Injection

Comment: this is simply DI and not clearly explaining IOC ,what about 2nd and 3rd answer ?

Comment: Your IoC example is dependency injection, the code shown has nothing to do with inversion of control.

Comment: "There is some confusion these days over the meaning of inversion of control due to the rise of IoC containers; some people confuse the general principle here with the specific styles of inversion of control (such as dependency injection) that these containers use." - https://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html

Comment: IoC and DI are not patterns. They are principles. Also using name like `IocSpellChecker` drive me to sadness. Much better would be 'IoCDesignatedTextBox' in this case but still not too nice. And generally Ioc is not only about inverting of dependencies creation. I think it is about whole life: If we are not a water pumping facility but casual programmer then if we want drink we do not go out and pumping the water but just letting some external company inject it into our kitchen ;)

Comment: I am really surprised how this wrong answer is upvoted like that

Comment: So so much clearer than other explanations.  But as the other commenters adroitly pointed out, this Wikipedia explanation is more correct: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control#Examples

Comment: The 2nd answer is also more correct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3108/6565511

Answer (score 809):

Inversion of Control is what you get when your program callbacks, e.g. like a gui program.

For example, in an old school menu, you might have:

```
print "enter your name"
read name
print "enter your address"
read address
etc...
store in database
```

thereby controlling the flow of user interaction.

In a GUI program or somesuch, instead we say:

```
when the user types in field a, store it in NAME
when the user types in field b, store it in ADDRESS
when the user clicks the save button, call StoreInDatabase
```

So now control is inverted... instead of the computer accepting user input in a fixed order, the user controls the order in which the data is entered, and when the data is saved in the database.

Basically, **anything** with an event loop, callbacks, or execute triggers falls into this category.

Comment: dont mark this guy down. technically he is correct http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html IoC is a very general principal. Flow of control is "inverted" by dependency injection because you have effectively delegated dependancies to some external system (e.g. IoC container)

Comment: Indeed, this is one of the few *correct* anwsers! Guys, IoC is *not* fundamentally about dependencies. Not at all.

Comment: +1 - This is a good description (with example) of the following statement by Martin Fowler - "Early user interfaces were controlled by the application program. You would have a sequence of commands like "Enter name", "enter address"; your program would drive the prompts and pick up a response to each one. With graphical (or even screen based) UIs the UI framework would contain this main loop and your program instead provided event handlers for the various fields on the screen. The main control of the program was inverted, moved away from you to the framework."

Comment: I now get it why it is sometimes facetiously referred to as the "Hollywood Principle: Don't call us, we'll call you"

Comment: Why not modify the poster's question to refer to DI specifically, because this as it stands is one of the most confusing answers on SO.

Comment: I've been looking for a very very clear explanation of IoC. I find @Schneider concept almost revealing, helping me to understand better abstract concepts as DIP, DI and IoC. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @iliketocode, before the inversion who was controlling the flow : the computer or the user ? How ?

Comment: Much better answer than the one accepted standing that IoC is pattern and automatically connecting it with DI also calling it pattern. True is that neither IoC or DI isn't pattern but principles

Comment: Sir, the more explanations come in, the more confusing it gets. Every answer here seems pointing some-thing familiar like Event-Drive Programming (in your case) and Modular programming etc.

Comment: If we follow this definition, how then would you separate the definitions of IoC to declarative programming?

Comment: @JackUkleja +1 for the link you attached to your comment, it is the most simple and clear answer I have ever read till now about IOC

Answer (score 504):

What is Inversion of Control?

If you follow these simple two steps, you have done inversion of control:

1. Separate **what**-to-do part from **when**-to-do part.
2. Ensure that **when** part knows as *little* as possible about **what** part; and vice versa.

There are several techniques possible for each of these steps based on the technology/language you are using for your implementation.

--

The *inversion* part of the Inversion of Control (IoC) is the confusing thing; because *inversion* is the relative term. The best way to understand IoC is to forget about that word!

--

Examples

- Event Handling. Event Handlers (what-to-do part) -- Raising Events (when-to-do part)
- Dependency Injection. Code that constructs a dependency (what-to-do part) -- instantiating and injecting that dependency for the clients when needed, which is usually taken care of by the DI tools such as Dagger (when-to-do-part).
- Interfaces. Component client (when-to-do part) -- Component Interface implementation (what-to-do part)
- xUnit fixture. Setup and TearDown (what-to-do part) -- xUnit frameworks calls to Setup at the beginning and TearDown at the end (when-to-do part)
- Template method design pattern. template method when-to-do part -- primitive subclass implementation what-to-do part
- DLL container methods in COM. DllMain, DllCanUnload, etc (what-to-do part) -- COM/OS (when-to-do part)

Comment: How you are saying Interfaces. Component client (when-to-do part) as "when" does not make sense when we use interfaces ( Ex: Dependency Injection), we just abstract it out and give the client flexibility about adding any implementation but there is no "when" involved there. I agree with "when" in case of Raising Events of Event Handling.

Comment: By 'component client' I meant the user / client of the interface. The client knows 'when' to trigger the 'what-to-do' part whether the intention is to extend the functionality or not.

Comment: Take a look at this wonderful article by Martin Fowler. He shows how interfaces make the fundamental part of inversion of control: https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#InversionOfControl

Comment: two first sentences are brilliant. awesome !! perfect separating by when-to-do and what-to-do !! i dont know why other answers get that many of upvotes. they just talking codes without any understandings.

Comment: @rpattabi, give an example in code of what you said in the answer

Comment: If we follow this definition, how then would you separate the definitions of IoC to declarative programming?

Answer (score 222):

Inversion of Controls is about separating concerns.

**Without IoC**: You have a **laptop** computer and you accidentally break the screen. And darn, you find the same model laptop screen is nowhere in the market. So you're stuck.

**With IoC**: You have a **desktop** computer and you accidentally break the screen. You find you can just grab almost any desktop monitor from the market, and it works well with your desktop.

Your desktop successfully implements IoC in this case. It accepts a variety type of monitors, while the laptop does not, it needs a specific screen to get fixed.

Comment: @Luo Jiong Hui  Nice explanation.

Comment: Most of Design patterns, if not all, have their counterparts in our daily life that we see and understand so well. The most efficient way of understanding a design pattern is to know their daily life counterparts. And I believe there are many.

Comment: Incorrect answer.  You are explaining _dependency injection_ and not IoC.  See  Rogério's comment on [this answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3140/585968)

Comment: I agree. This is DI, not IoC. Still gets an upvote from, because it is a simple approach, yet helps expand the understanding of the topic.

Comment: It explains the dependency injection. Not Ioc. But nice and clear explanation.

Comment: Late to the party, but this is acutally Dependency Inversion. Dependency Inversion is almost every time used with  Dependency Injection, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: @user585968 DI is an application of IOC

Answer (score 171):

Inversion of Control, (or IoC), is about **getting freedom** (You get married, you lost freedom and you are being controlled. You divorced, you have just implemented Inversion of Control. That's what we called, "decoupled". Good computer system discourages some very close relationship.) **more flexibility** (The kitchen in your office only serves clean tap water, that is your only choice when you want to drink. Your boss implemented Inversion of Control by setting up a new coffee machine. Now you get the flexibility of choosing either tap water or coffee.) and **less dependency** (Your partner has a job, you don't have a job, you financially depend on your partner, so you are controlled. You find a job, you have implemented Inversion of Control. Good computer system encourages in-dependency.)

When you use a desktop computer, you have slaved (or say, controlled). You have to sit before a screen and look at it. Using the keyboard to type and using the mouse to navigate. And a badly written software can slave you even more. If you replace your desktop with a laptop, then you somewhat inverted control. You can easily take it and move around. So now you can control where you are with your computer, instead of your computer controlling it.

By implementing Inversion of Control, a software/object consumer gets more controls/options over the software/objects, instead of being controlled or having fewer options.

With the above ideas in mind. We still miss a key part of IoC. In the scenario of IoC, the software/object consumer is a sophisticated framework. That means the code you created is not called by yourself. Now let's explain why this way works better for a web application.

Suppose your code is a group of workers. They need to build a car. These workers need a place and tools (a software framework) to build the car. A **traditional** software framework will be like a garage with many tools. So the workers need to make a plan themselves and use the tools to build the car. Building a car is not an easy business, it will be really hard for the workers to plan and cooperate properly. A **modern** software framework will be like a modern car factory with all the facilities and managers in place. The workers do not have to make any plan, the managers (part of the framework, they are the smartest people and made the most sophisticated plan) will help coordinate so that the workers know when to do their job (framework calls your code). The workers just need to be flexible enough to use any tools the managers give to them (by using Dependency Injection).

Although the workers give the control of managing the project on the top level to the managers (the framework). But it is good to have some professionals help out. This is the concept of IoC truly come from.

Modern Web applications with an MVC architecture depends on the framework to do URL Routing and put Controllers in place for the framework to call.

Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control are related. Dependency Injection is at the **micro** level and Inversion of Control is at the **macro** level. You have to eat every bite (implement DI) in order to finish a meal (implement IoC).

Comment: " Although the workers give the control of managing the project on the top level to the managers (the framework). But it is good to have some professionals help out. This is the concept of IoC truly come from. " -  Firstly the control is with the Manager. Can you explain how that control is  inverted ? With the help of professionals (what kind of professional) ? How ?

Comment: @Istiaque Ahmed, comparing to a garage where workers have full control of everything, managers in modern car factory control the production. So now workers are controlled instead of controlling. Be aware, managers in this context is part of modern car factory, not part of the workers. Professionals are the managers who are professional at planning and making cars.

Answer (score 109):

Before using Inversion of Control you should be well aware of the fact that it has its pros and cons and you should know why you use it if you do so.

Pros:

- Your code gets decoupled so you can easily exchange implementations of an interface with alternative implementations
- It is a strong motivator for coding against interfaces instead of implementations
- It's very easy to write unit tests for your code because it depends on nothing else than the objects it accepts in its constructor/setters and you can easily initialize them with the right objects in isolation.

Cons:

- IoC not only inverts the control flow in your program, it also clouds it considerably. This means you can no longer just read your code and jump from one place to another because the connections that would normally be in your code are not in the code anymore. Instead it is in XML configuration files or annotations and in the code of your IoC container that interprets these metadata.
- There arises a new class of bugs where you get your XML config or your annotations wrong and you can spend a lot of time finding out why your IoC container injects a null reference into one of your objects under certain conditions.

Personally I see the strong points of IoC and I really like them but I tend to avoid IoC whenever possible because it turns your software into a collection of classes that no longer constitute a "real" program but just something that needs to be put together by XML configuration or annotation metadata and would fall (and falls) apart without it.

Comment: The first con is incorrect. Ideally there should only be 1 use of IOC container in your code, and that is your main method. Everything else should cascade down from there

Comment: I think what he means is, you can't just read: myService.DoSomething() and go to the definition of DoSomething, because with IoC, myService is just an interface, and the actual implementation is unknown to you, unless you go look it up in xml config files or the main method where your ioc gets setup.

Comment: That is where Resharper helps - "click go to implementation" against the interface. Avoiding IoC (or more specifically DI from your example) probably also means you aren't testing properly

Comment: Re: _it turns your software into a collection of classes that no longer constitute a "real" program but just something that needs to be put together by XML configuration or annotation metadata and would fall (and falls) apart without it_ -- I think this is very misleading. The same could be said of any program that is written on top of a framework. The difference with a good IoC container is that you should be able to, if your program is well designed & written, take it out and plop in another one with minimal changes to your code, or toss out IoC altogether and construct your objects by hand.

Comment: Good to see a real-world answer like this! I think there are plenty of experienced programmers, comfortable with object orientated design and TDD practices, already using interfaces, factory patterns, event driven models and mocking where it makes sense, before this "IoC" buzzword was invented. Unfortunately too many developers/"architects" claim bad practice if you don't use their preferred frameworks. I prefer a better design, use of built-in language concepts and tools, to achieve the same goal with a fraction of the complexity, i.e. without "clouding" the implementation as you say :-)

Comment: You can do dependency injection without interfaces, annotations, or any framework support. At a minimum, all you need is classes that do stuff that have constructors that take instances of other objects they need. The big difference is you don't allow these classes to create things themselves. A simple main method can take the role of the dependency injection frameworks and simply call new on each object. Writing this main method is tedious. But the rest of your code stays readable and clean and having the plumbing in one place is actually nice as well.

Comment: I think you are concluding your cons based on XML-based frameworks like Spring for Java. IoC is way wider than only injecting dependencies through XML descriptors.

Comment: @JillesvanGurp I think your point about the main method is really important, writing your own simple framework to have full control over the plumbing of a program is as valid as using a premade one.

Answer (score 78):

1. [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). To me, inversion of control is turning your sequentially written code and turning it into an delegation structure. Instead of your program explicitly controlling everything, your program sets up a class or library with certain functions to be called when certain things happen.
2. It solves code duplication. For example, in the old days you would manually write your own event loop, polling the system libraries for new events. Nowadays, most modern APIs you simply tell the system libraries what events you're interested in, and it will let you know when they happen.
3. Inversion of control is a practical way to reduce code duplication, and if you find yourself copying an entire method and only changing a small piece of the code, you can consider tackling it with inversion of control. Inversion of control is made easy in many languages through the concept of delegates, interfaces, or even raw function pointers.

   It is not appropriate to use in all cases, because the flow of a program can be harder to follow when written this way. It's a useful way to design methods when writing a library that will be reused, but it should be used sparingly in the core of your own program unless it really solves a code duplication problem.

Comment: I find that Wikipedia article very confusing and in need of fixing up. Check out the discussion page for a laugh.

Comment: Writing your own event loop could still be inversion of control, if that event loop takes the place of a framework and the rest of the code is using IoC principle you have just written your own framework. This is actually not a bad thing, it increases readability at the price of only a little bit more coding (not that it is always appropriate either).

Answer (score 54):

Answering only the first part.
What is it?

Inversion of Control (IoC) means to create instances of dependencies first and latter instance of a class (optionally injecting them through constructor), instead of creating an instance of the class first and then the class instance creating instances of dependencies.
Thus, inversion of control **inverts** the **flow of control** of the program. **Instead of** the **callee controlling** the **flow of control** (while creating dependencies), the **caller controls the flow of control of the program**.

Comment: Its not about class or object creation, check this http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#InversionOfControl

Comment: In my 15 years of programming this is by far the clearest explanation of what IoC is. Thanks!

The main answer *does not say* it is about class or object creation, with all due respect.  It says what inversion of control is using the creation of classes AS AN EXAMPLE. :)

And the author uses a minimum of sentences and words with which to communicate the answer!

With all due respect, this answer is the best one in the article. WHY is it one of the last entries to be found ...

Comment: This is a very good explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 52):

Suppose you are an object. And you go to a restaurant:

**Without IoC**: you ask for "apple", and you are always served apple when you ask more.

**With IoC**: You can ask for "fruit". You can get different fruits each time you get served. for example, apple, orange, or water melon.

So, obviously, IoC is preferred when you like the varieties.

Answer (score 47):

But I think you have to be very careful with it. If you will overuse this pattern, you will make very complicated design and even more complicated code.

Like in this example with TextEditor: if you have only one SpellChecker maybe it is not really necessary to use IoC ? Unless you need to write unit tests or something ...

Anyway: be reasonable. Design pattern are **good practices** but not Bible to be preached. Do not stick it everywhere.

Comment: How do you know that you will only have one spellchecker?

Comment: @Trace You could know how the program you are going to write is going to get used for example. Still some techniques such as dependency injection is so cheap that there is rarely a reason not to use them in a case like this.

Answer (score 46):

IoC / DI to me is pushing out dependencies to the calling objects. Super simple.

The non-techy answer is being able to swap out an engine in a car right before you turn it on. If everything hooks up right (the interface), you are good.

Answer (score 27):

1. Inversion of control is a pattern used for decoupling components and layers in the system. The pattern is implemented through injecting dependencies into a component when it is constructed. These dependences are usually provided as interfaces for further decoupling and to support testability. IoC / DI containers such as Castle Windsor, Unity are tools (libraries) which can be used for providing IoC. These tools provide extended features above and beyond simple dependency management, including lifetime, AOP / Interception, policy, etc.
2. a. Alleviates a component from being responsible for managing it's dependencies.
   b. Provides the ability to swap dependency implementations in different environments.
   c. Allows a component be tested through mocking of dependencies.
   d. Provides a mechanism for sharing resources throughout an application.
3. a. Critical when doing test-driven development. Without IoC it can be difficult to test, because the components under test are highly coupled to the rest of the system.
   b. Critical when developing modular systems. A modular system is a system whose components can be replaced without requiring recompilation.
   c. Critical if there are many cross-cutting concerns which need to addressed, partilarly in an enterprise application.

Comment: Actually, IoC isn't mainly about managing dependencies.
Please see http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#InversionOfControl In particular, note the part saying "Inversion of Control is too generic a term, and thus people find it confusing. As a result with a lot of discussion with various IoC advocates we settled on the name Dependency Injection".

Answer (score 27):

Let's say that we have a meeting in a hotel.

We have invited many people, so we have left out many jugs of water and many plastic cups.

When somebody wants to drink, he/she fills a cup, drinks the water and throws the cup on the floor.

After an hour or so we have a floor covered with plastic cups and water.

Let's try that after inverting the control:

Imagine the same meeting in the same place, but instead of plastic cups we now have a waiter with just one glass cup (Singleton)

When somebody wants to drink, the waiter gets one for them. They drink it and return it to the waiter.

Leaving aside the question of the hygiene, the use of a waiter (process control) is much more effective and economic.

And this is exactly what Spring (another IoC container, for example: Guice) does. Instead of letting the application create what it needs using the new keyword (i.e. taking a plastic cup), Spring IoC offers the application the same cup/ instance (singleton) of the needed object (glass of water).

Think of yourself as an organizer of such a meeting:

**Example:-**

```
public class MeetingMember {

    private GlassOfWater glassOfWater;

    ...

    public void setGlassOfWater(GlassOfWater glassOfWater){
        this.glassOfWater = glassOfWater;
    }
    //your glassOfWater object initialized and ready to use...
    //spring IoC  called setGlassOfWater method itself in order to
    //offer to meetingMember glassOfWater instance

}
```

**Useful links:-**

- http://adfjsf.blogspot.in/2008/05/inversion-of-control.html
- http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html
- http://www.shawn-barrett.com/blog/post/Tip-of-the-day-e28093-Inversion-Of-Control.aspx

Comment: aren't singletons static type objects?

Comment: You explained Dependency Injection, and it's different term than inversion of control. Dependency Injection Container is an implementation of Inversion of Control.

Answer (score 23):

**I shall write down my simple understanding of this two terms:**

```
For quick understanding just read examples*
```

**Dependency Injection(DI):**
Dependency injection generally means **passing an object on which method depends, as a parameter to a method, rather than having the method create the dependent object**. 
What it means in practice is that the method does not depends directly on a particular implementation; any implementation that meets the requirements can be passed as a parameter.
*With this objects tell thier dependencies.
And spring makes it available. 
This leads to loosely coupled application development.*

```
Quick Example:EMPLOYEE OBJECT WHEN CREATED,
              IT WILL AUTOMATICALLY CREATE ADDRESS OBJECT
   (if address is defines as dependency by Employee object)
```

**Inversion of Control(IoC) Container:**
This is common characteristic of frameworks,
IOC **manages java objects** 
– from instantiation to destruction through its BeanFactory. 
-Java components that are instantiated by the IoC container are called beans, and the **IoC container manages a bean's scope, lifecycle events, and any AOP features** for which it has been configured and coded.

*`QUICK EXAMPLE:Inversion of Control is about getting freedom, more flexibility, and less dependency. When you are using a desktop computer, you are slaved (or say, controlled). You have to sit before a screen and look at it. Using keyboard to type and using mouse to navigate. And a bad written software can slave you even more. If you replaced your desktop with a laptop, then you somewhat inverted control. You can easily take it and move around. So now you can control where you are with your computer, instead of computer controlling it`*.

By implementing Inversion of Control, a software/object consumer get more controls/options over the software/objects, instead of being controlled or having less options.

**Inversion of control as a design guideline serves the following purposes:**

There is a decoupling of the execution of a certain task from implementation.
Every module can focus on what it is designed for.
Modules make no assumptions about what other systems do but rely on their contracts.
Replacing modules has no side effect on other modules
 I will keep things abstract here, You can visit following links for detail understanding of the topic.
[A good read with example](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-basic-constructor-injection.html)

[Detailed explanation](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/03/19/inversion-of-control-ioc-and-dependency-injection-di-patterns-in-spring-framework-and-related-interview-questions/)

Answer (score 22):

I found a very clear example [here](http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html) which explains how the 'control is inverted'.

**Classic code (without Dependency injection)**

Here is how a code not using DI will roughly work:

- Application needs Foo (e.g. a controller), so:
- Application creates Foo
- Application calls Foo

  - Foo needs Bar (e.g. a service), so:
  - Foo creates Bar
  - Foo calls Bar

    - Bar needs Bim (a service, a repository, …), so:
    - Bar creates Bim
    - Bar does something

**Using dependency injection**

Here is how a code using DI will roughly work:

- Application needs Foo, which needs Bar, which needs Bim, so:
- Application creates Bim
- Application creates Bar and gives it Bim
- Application creates Foo and gives it Bar
- Application calls Foo

  - Foo calls Bar

    - Bar does something

***The control of the dependencies is inverted from one being called to the one calling.***

**What problems does it solve?**

Dependency injection makes it easy to swap with the different implementation of the injected classes. While unit testing you can inject a dummy implementation, which makes the testing a lot easier.

Ex: Suppose your application stores the user uploaded file in the Google Drive, with DI your controller code may look like this:

```
class SomeController
{
    private $storage;

    function __construct(StorageServiceInterface $storage)
    {
        $this->storage = $storage;
    }

    public function myFunction () 
    {
        return $this->storage->getFile($fileName);
    }
}

class GoogleDriveService implements StorageServiceInterface
{
    public function authenticate($user) {}
    public function putFile($file) {}
    public function getFile($file) {}
}
```

When your requirements change say, instead of GoogleDrive you are asked to use the Dropbox. You only need to write a dropbox implementation for the StorageServiceInterface. You don't have make any changes in the controller as long as Dropbox implementation adheres to the StorageServiceInterface.

While testing you can create the mock for the StorageServiceInterface with the dummy implementation where all the methods return null(or any predefined value as per your testing requirement).

Instead if you had the controller class to construct the storage object with the `new` keyword like this:

```
class SomeController
{
    private $storage;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->storage = new GoogleDriveService();
    }

    public function myFunction () 
    {
        return $this->storage->getFile($fileName);
    }
}
```

When you want to change with the Dropbox implementation you have to replace all the lines where `new` GoogleDriveService object is constructed and use the DropboxService. Besides when testing the SomeController class the constructor always expects the GoogleDriveService class and the actual methods of this class are triggered.

**When is it appropriate and when not?**
In my opinion you use DI when you think there are (or there can be) alternative implementations of a class.

Comment: This should be the most correct answer as its the only one explains how the "control" is inverted.

Comment: best explanation so far

Answer (score 20):

I agree with [NilObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058/what-is-inversion-of-control#3082), but I'd like to add to this:

> if you find yourself copying an entire method and only changing a small piece of the code, you can consider tackling it with inversion of control

If you find yourself copying and pasting code around, you're almost always doing *something* wrong.  Codified as the design principle [Once and Only Once](http://c2.com/xp/OnceAndOnlyOnce.html).

Answer (score 18):

For example, task#1 is to create object.
Without IOC concept, task#1 is supposed to be done by Programmer.But With IOC concept, task#1 would be done by container.

In short Control gets inverted from Programmer to container. So, it is called as inversion of control.

I found one good example [here](http://www.goospoos.com/2009/12/inversion-of-control-basics-with-example/).

Comment: A container is a concept in IoC where the object model, including dependencies (relationships between "user" object and "used" object) and object instances, reside and is managed -- e.g., contained. The container is usually provided by a IoC framework, such as Spring. Think of it as a runtime repository for the objects that make up your application.

Answer (score 18):

It seems that the most confusing thing about "IoC" the acronym and the name for which it stands is that it's too glamorous of a name - almost a noise name.

Do we really need a name by which to describe the difference between procedural and event driven programming? OK, if we need to, but do we need to pick a brand new "bigger than life" name that confuses more than it solves?

Comment: IoC != event driven. Similarities (and in some cases overlap), but they are not principally the same paradigm.

Comment: Good question. Event driven programming IS certainly IoC. We write event handlers and they get called from event loop. But, IoC is more generic concept than Event driven programming..

If you override a method in subclass, it is also a kind of IoC. You write a code that would get invoked when appropriate reference (instance) was used.

Answer (score 18):

**Inversion of control** is when you go to the grocery store and your wife gives you the list of products to buy.

In programming terms, she passed a callback function `getProductList()` to the function you are executing - `doShopping()`.

It allows user of the function to define some parts of it, making it more flexible.

Comment: My wife usually shops with me, but I agree with this statement.

Comment: @ha9u63ar Your wife shops with you? Well that's called aggregation then.

Comment: If she gives the money as well, it is called DI.

Comment: The word Inversion - upside down - came from, when your wife calls `getProductList()` you have to find the source for money, means the control is at your side. In the case of inversion, she will controll, means the money also she will provide to buy.

Answer (score 15):

Inversion of Control is a generic principle, while Dependency Injection realises this principle as a design pattern for object graph construction (i.e. configuration controls how the objects are referencing each other, rather than the object itself controlling how to get the reference to another object).

Looking at Inversion of Control as a design pattern, we need to look at what we are inverting.  Dependency Injection inverts control of constructing a graph of objects. If told in layman's term, inversion of control implies change in flow of control in the program. Eg. In traditional standalone app, we have main method, from where the control gets passed to other third party libraries(in case, we have used third party library's function), but through inversion of control control gets transferred from third party library code to our code, as we are taking the service of third party library.  But there are other aspects that need to be inverted within a program - e.g. invocation of methods and threads to execute the code.

For those interested in more depth on Inversion of Control a paper has been published outlining a more complete picture of Inversion of Control as a design pattern (OfficeFloor: using office patterns to improve software design http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2739011.2739013 with a free copy available to download from http://www.officefloor.net/about.html).

What is identified is the following relationship:

Inversion of Control (for methods) = Dependency (state) Injection + Continuation Injection + Thread Injection

Summary of above relationship for Inversion of Control available -  http://dzone.com/articles/inversion-of-coupling-control

Comment: This is a very clear answer. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 15):

I understand that the answer has already been given here. But I still think, some basics about the inversion of control have to be discussed here in length for future readers.

Inversion of Control (IoC) has been built on a very simple principle called **Hollywood Principle**. And it says that,

> Don't call us, we'll call you

What it means is that don't go to the Hollywood to fulfill your dream rather if you are worthy then Hollywood will find you and make your dream comes true. Pretty much inverted, huh?

Now when we discuss about the principle of IoC, we use to forget about the Hollywood. For IoC, there has to be three element, a Hollywood, you and a task like to fulfill your dream.

In our programming world, **Hollywood** represent a generic framework (may be written by you or someone else), **you** represent the user code you wrote and **the task** represent the thing you want to accomplish with your code. Now you don't ever go to trigger your task by yourself, not in IoC! Rather you have designed everything in such that your framework will trigger your task for you. Thus you have built a reusable framework which can make someone a hero or another one a villain. But that framework is always in charge, it knows when to pick someone and that someone only knows what it wants to be.

A real life example would be given here. Suppose, you want to develop a web application. So, you create a framework which will handle all the common things a web application should handle like handling http request, creating application menu, serving pages, managing cookies, triggering events etc.

And then you leave some hooks in your framework where you can put further codes to generate custom menu, pages, cookies or logging some user events etc. On every browser request, your framework will run and executes your custom codes if hooked then serve it back to the browser.

So, the idea is pretty much simple. Rather than creating a user application which will control everything, first you create a reusable framework which will control everything then write your custom codes and hook it to the framework to execute those in time.

Laravel and EJB are examples of such a frameworks.

Reference:

https://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control

Comment: The most appropriate answer I found here.

Answer (score 13):

A very simple written explanation can be found here

http://binstock.blogspot.in/2008/01/excellent-explanation-of-dependency.html

It says -

> "Any nontrivial application is made up of two or more classes that
>   collaborate with each other to perform some business logic.
>   Traditionally, each object is responsible for obtaining its own
>   references to the objects it collaborates with (its dependencies).
>   When applying DI, the objects are given their dependencies at creation
>   time by some external entity that coordinates each object in the
>   system. In other words, dependencies are injected into objects."

Answer (score 13):

IoC is about inverting the relationship between your code and third-party code (library/framework):

- In normal s/w development, you write the ***main()*** method and call "library" methods.  ***You*** are in control :)
- In IoC the "framework" controls ***main()*** and calls your methods. The ***Framework*** is in control :(

DI (Dependency Injection) is about how the control flows in the application. Traditional desktop application had control flow from your application(main() method) to other library method calls, but with DI control flow is inverted that's framework takes care of starting your app, initializing it and invoking your methods whenever required.

In the end you always win :)

Answer (score 13):

I like this explanation: http://joelabrahamsson.com/inversion-of-control-an-introduction-with-examples-in-net/

It start simple and shows code examples as well.

[image]

The consumer, X, needs the consumed class, Y, to accomplish something. That’s all good and natural, but does X really need to know that it uses Y?

Isn’t it enough that X knows that it uses something that has the behavior, the methods, properties etc, of Y without knowing who actually implements the behavior?

By extracting an abstract definition of the behavior used by X in Y, illustrated as I below, and letting the consumer X use an instance of that instead of Y it can continue to do what it does without having to know the specifics about Y.

[image]

In the illustration above Y implements I and X uses an instance of I. While it’s quite possible that X still uses Y what’s interesting is that X doesn’t know that. It just knows that it uses something that implements I.

Read article for further info and description of benefits such as:

- X is not dependent on Y anymore
- More flexible, implementation can be decided in runtime
- Isolation of code unit, easier testing

...

Comment: The link is very helpful. Really Thanks :)

Answer (score 12):

Since there already are many answers to the question but none of them shows some breakdown of the Inversion of Control term, I see an opportunity to give a more concise and helpful answer.

Inversion of Control is a pattern that implements the Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP). The DIP states the following: 1. High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions (e.g. interfaces). 2. Abstractions should not depend on details. Details (concrete implementations) should depend on abstractions.

There are three types of Inversion of Control:

**Interface Inversion**
Providers shouldn’t define an interface. Instead, the consumer should define the interface and providers must implement it. Interface Inversion allows for eliminating the necessity to modify the consumer each time when a new provider is added.

**Flow Inversion**
Flow Inversion changes a program's flow control. For example, you have a console application where you are asked to enter many parameters, and after each entered parameter you are forced to press Enter. You can apply Flow Inversion here and implement a desktop application where the user can choose a sequence of parameters to enter, the user can edit parameters, and at the final step, the user needs to press Enter only once.

**Creation Inversion**
It can be implemented by the following patterns: Factory Pattern, Service Locator, and Dependency Injection. Creation Inversion helps to eliminate dependencies between types moving the process of necessary objects' creation outside of the program type that uses these dependency objects. Why are dependencies bad? Here are a couple of examples: direct creation of a new object in your code makes testing harder; it is impossible to change references in assemblies without recompilation (it causes a violation of the OCP principle); you can’t easily replace a desktop UI with a web UI.

Answer (score 11):

Programming speaking

IoC in easy terms: It's the use of Interface as a way of specific something (such a field or a parameter) as a wildcard that can be used by some classes. It allows the re-usability of the code.

For example, let's say that we have two classes : **Dog** and **Cat**.   Both shares the same qualities/states: age, size, weight. So instead of creating a class of service called **DogService** and **CatService**, I can create a single one called **AnimalService** that allows to use Dog and Cat only if they use the interface **IAnimal**.

However, pragmatically speaking, it has some backwards.

a) **Most of the developers don't know how to use it**.  For example, I can create a class called **Customer** and **I can create automatically** (using the tools of the IDE) an interface called **ICustomer**. So, it's not rare to find a folder filled with classes and interfaces, no matter if the interfaces will be reused or not. It's called BLOATED. Some people could argue that "may be in the future we could use it".  :-|

b) It has some limitings. For example, let's talk about the case of **Dog** and **Cat** and I want to add a new service (functionality) only for dogs.  Let's say that I want to calculate the number of days that I need to train a dog (**`trainDays()`**), for cat it's useless, cats can't be trained (I'm joking).

b.1) If I add `trainDays()` to the Service **AnimalService** then it also works with cats and it's not valid at all.

b.2) I can add a condition in `trainDays()` where it evaluates which class is used. But it will break completely the IoC.

b.3) I can create a new class of service called **DogService** just for the new functionality. But, it will increase the maintainability of the code because we will have two classes of service (with similar functionality) for **Dog** and it's bad.

Comment: About bloated classes/interfaces: You do not always have to reuse every single interface. Sometimes it just makes sense to split a large interface in to many smaller to see it's functional boundaries. Smaller interfaces are also easier to reuse in other implementations. Also it encourages you to code to an interface wherever it makes sense. Consider "Interface Segregation". Only because you're using an interface does not mean that you are decoupled. A single fat interface is useless. 

- Just my 2 cents :)

Answer (score 11):

Inversion of control is about transferring control from library to the client. It makes more sense when we talk about a client that injects (passes) a function value (lambda expression) into a higher order function (library function) that controls (changes) the behavior of the library function.

So, a simple implementation (with huge implications) of this pattern is a higher order library function (which accepts another function as an argument). The library function transfers control over its behavior by giving the client the ability to supply the "control" function as an argument.

For example, library functions like "map", "flatMap" are IoC implementations.

Of course, a limited IoC version is, for example, a boolean function parameter. A client may control the library function by switching the boolean argument.

A client or framework that injects library dependencies (which carry behavior) into libraries may also be considered IoC

Answer (score 9):

**I've read a lot of answers for this but if someone is still confused and needs a plus ultra "laymans term" to explain IoC here is my take:**

Imagine a parent and child talking to each other.

**Without IoC:**

***Parent**: You can only speak when I ask you questions and you can only act when I give you permission.

**Parent**: This means, you can't ask me if you can eat, play, go to the bathroom or even sleep if I don't ask you.

**Parent**: Do you want to eat?

**Child**: No.

**Parent**: Okay, I'll be back. Wait for me.

**Child**: (Wants to play but since there's no question from the parent, the child can't do anything).

*After 1 hour...*

**Parent**: I'm back. Do you want to play?

**Child**: Yes.

**Parent**: Permission granted.

**Child**: (finally is able to play).

This simple scenario explains the control is centered to the parent. The child's freedom is restricted and highly depends on the parent's question. The child can **ONLY** speak when asked to speak, and can **ONLY** act when granted permission.

**With IoC:**

The child has now the ability to ask questions and the parent can respond with answers and permissions. Simply means the control is inverted!
The child is now free to ask questions anytime and though there is still dependency with the parent regarding permissions, he is not dependent in the means of speaking/asking questions.

*In a technological way of explaining, this is very similar to console/shell/cmd vs GUI interaction. (Which is answer of Mark Harrison above no.2 top answer).
In console, you are dependent on the what is being asked/displayed to you and you can't jump to other menus and features without answering it's question first; following a strict sequential flow. (programmatically this is like a method/function loop).
However with GUI, the menus and features are laid out and the user can select whatever it needs thus having more **control** and being less restricted. (programmatically, menus have callback when selected and an action takes place).*

Answer (score 6):

Creating an object within class is called tight coupling, Spring removes this dependency by following a design pattern(DI/IOC). In which object of class in passed in constructor rather than creating in class. More over we give super class reference variable in constructor to define more general structure.

Answer (score 5):

I feel a little awkward answering this question with so many prior answers, but I just didn't think any of the answers just stated the concept simply enough.

So here we go...

In a non-IOC application, you would code a process flow and include all the detailed steps in it.  Consider a program that creates a report - it would include code to set up the printer connection, print a header, then iterate through detail records, then print a footer, maybe perform a page feed, etc.

In an IOC version of a report program, you would configure an instance of a generic, reusable Report class - that is, a class that contains the process flow for printing a report, but has none of the details in it.  The configuration you provide might use DI to specify what class the Report should call to print a header, what class the Report should call to print a detail line, and what class the Report should call to print the footer.

So the inversion of control comes from the controlling process not being your code, but rather contained in an external, reusable class (Report) that allows you to specify or inject (via DI) the details of the report - the header, the detail line, the footer.

You could produce any number of different reports using the same Report class (the controlling class) - by providing different sets of the detail classes.  You are inverting your control by relying on the Report class to provide it, and merely specifying the differences between reports via injection.

In some ways, IOC could be compared to a drive backup application - the backup always performs the same steps, but the set of files backed up can be completely different.

And now to answer the original questions specifically...

- What is it?  IOC is relying on a reusable controller class and providing the details specific to your problem at hand.
- Which problem does it solve?  Prevents you from having to restate a controlling process flow.
- When is it appropriate to use and when not?  Whenever you are creating a process flow where the control flow is always the same, and only the details are changed.  You would not use it when creating a one-off, custom process flow.

Finally, IOC is not DI, and DI is not IOC - DI can often be used in IOC (in order to state the details of the abstracted control class).

Anyway - I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Using IoC you are not new'ing up your objects. Your IoC container will do that and manage the lifetime of them.

It solves the problem of having to manually change every instantiation of one type of object to another.

It is appropriate when you have functionality that may change in the future or that may be different depending on the environment or configuration used in.

Answer (score 4):

To understanding the concept, Inversion of Control (IoC) or Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP) involves two activities: abstraction, and inversion.
Dependency Injection (DI) is just one of the few of the inversion methods.

To read more about this you can read my blog  [Here](http://kusnaditjung.blogspot.co.uk/2016/05/dependency-inversion-principle-dip.html)

1. What is it?

It is a practice where you let the actual behavior come from outside of the boundary (Class in Object Oriented Programming). The boundary entity only knows the abstraction (e.g interface, abstract class, delegate in Object Oriented Programming) of it.

2. What problems does it solve?

In term of programming, IoC try to solve monolithic code by making it modular, decoupling various parts of it, and make it unit-testable.

3. When is it appropriate and when not?

It is appropriate most of the time, unless you have situation where you just want monolithic code (e.g very simple program)

Answer (score 3):

1. So number 1 [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058/what-is-inversion-of-control#99100). [What is Inversion of Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058/what-is-inversion-of-control#99100)
2. Maintenance is the number one thing it solves for me.  It guarantees I am using interfaces so that two classes are not intimate with each other.

In using a container like Castle Windsor, it solves maintenance issues even better.  Being able to swap out a component that goes to a database for one that uses file based persistence without changing a line of code is awesome (configuration change, you're done).

And once you get into generics, it gets even better.  Imagine having a message publisher that receives records and publishes messages.  It doesn't care what it publishes, but it needs a mapper to take something from a record to a message.

```
public class MessagePublisher<RECORD,MESSAGE>
{
    public MessagePublisher(IMapper<RECORD,MESSAGE> mapper,IRemoteEndpoint endPointToSendTo)
    {
      //setup
    }
}
```

I wrote it once, but now I can inject many types into this set of code if I publish different types of messages.  I can also write mappers that take a record of the same type and map them to different messages. Using DI with Generics has given me the ability to write very little code to accomplish many tasks.

Oh yeah, there are testability concerns, but they are secondary to the benefits of IoC/DI.

I am definitely loving IoC/DI.

3 . It becomes more appropriate the minute you have a medium sized project of somewhat more complexity.  I would say it becomes appropriate the minute you start feeling pain.

Comment: http://ferventcoder.com/archive/2008/12/14/the-real-reason-to-use-a-dependency-injection-container-like.aspx

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Really not understanding why there are lots of wrong answers and even the accepted is not quite accurate making things hard to understand. The truth is always simple and clean.</sub>

As [@Schneider commented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3108/2361308#comment-1186335) in [@Mark Harrison's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3108/2361308), please just read Martin Fowler's post discussing IoC.

https://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html

One of the most I love is:

> This phenomenon is Inversion of Control (also known as the Hollywood Principle - "Don't call us, we'll call you").

Why?

[Wiki for IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control), I might quote a snippet.

> Inversion of control is used to increase modularity of the program and make it extensible ... then further popularized in 2004 by **Robert C. Martin** and **Martin Fowler**.

Robert C. Martin: the author of `<<Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship>>`.

Martin Fowler: the author of `<<Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code>>`.

Answer (score 2):

Inversion of control means you control how components (classes) behave. Why its called "inversion" because before this pattern the classes were hard wired and were definitive about what they will do e.g.

you import a library that has a `TextEditor` and `SpellChecker` classes. Now naturally this `SpellChecker` would only check spellings for English language. Suppose if you want the `TextEditor` to handle German language and be able to spell check you have any control over it.

with IoC this control is inverted i.e. its given to you, how? the library would implement something like this:

It will have a `TextEditor` class and then it will have a `ISpeallChecker` (which is an interface instead of a concret `SpellChecker` class) and when you configure things in IoC container e.g. Spring you can provide your own implementation of 'ISpellChecker' which will check spelling for German language. so the control of how spell checking will work is ineverted is taken from that Library and given to you. Thats IoC.

Answer (score 1):

**What is it?**  Inversion of (Coupling) Control, changes the direction of coupling for the method signature.  With inverted control, the definition of the method signature is dictated by the method implementation (rather than the caller of the method). [Full explanation here](https://dzone.com/articles/inversion-of-coupling-control)

**Which problem does it solve?**  Top down coupling on methods.  This subsequently removes need for refactoring.

**When is it appropriate to use and when not?**  For small well defined applications that are not subject to much change, it is likely an overhead.  However, for less defined applications that will evolve, it reduces the inherent coupling of the method signature.  This gives the developers more freedom to evolve the application, avoiding the need to do expensive refactoring of code.  Basically, allows the application to evolve with little rework.

Answer (score 1):

To understand IoC, we should talk about Dependency Inversion.

Dependency inversion: Depend on abstractions, not on concretions.

Inversion of control: Main vs Abstraction, and how the Main is the glue of the systems.

[image: DIP and IoC]

I wrote about this with some good examples, you can check them here:

https://coderstower.com/2019/03/26/dependency-inversion-why-you-shouldnt-avoid-it/

https://coderstower.com/2019/04/02/main-and-abstraction-the-decoupled-peers/

https://coderstower.com/2019/04/09/inversion-of-control-putting-all-together/

Answer (score 0):

I think of Inversion of Control in the context of using a library or a framework.

The traditional way of "control" is that we build a controller class (usually main, but it could be anything), import a library and then use your controller class to "control" the action of the software components. Like your first C/Python program (after Hello World).

```
import pandas as pd
df = new DataFrame()
# Now do things with the dataframe.
```

In this case, we need to know what a Dataframe is in order to work with it. You need to know what methods to use, how values it takes and so on. If you add it to your own class through polymorphism or just calling it anew, your class will need the DataFrame library to work properly.

"Inversion of Control" means that the process is reversed. Instead of your classes controlling elements of a library, framework or engine, you register classes and send them back to the engine to be controlled. Worded another way, IoC can mean we are using our code to configuring a framework. You could also think of it as similar to the way we use functions in `map` or `filter` to deal with data in a list, except apply that to an entire application.

If you are the one who has built the engine, then you are probably using Dependency Injection approaches (described above) to make that happen. If you are the one using the engine (more common), then you should be able to just declare classes, add appropriate notations and let the framework do the rest of the work (e.g. creating routes, assigning servlets, setting events, outputting widgets etc.) for you.

Answer (score 0):

I try my best to give a simple and understandable answer (may not be accurate).

Each class or module should focus on doing just one main task(SRP). If it needs to do something else, a different class or module should handle that other task(IoC).

E.g: I have a calculator class/module that sends the result to the user via email.
The email part should be done in another class/module that we can use in the calculator class/module.( we inverted the "email task" from the calculator class to the email class )

Note, single responsibility and IoC go hand in hand.

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/ioc

Answer (score -1):

Inversion of control is an indicator for a shift of responsibility in the program.

There is an inversion of control every time when a dependency is granted ability to directly act on the caller's space.

The smallest IoC is passing a variable by reference, lets look at non-IoC code first:

```
function isVarHello($var) {
    return ($var === "Hello");
}

// Responsibility is within the caller
$word = "Hello";
if (isVarHello($word)) {
    $word = "World";
}
```

Let's now invert the control by shifting the responsibility of a result from the caller to the dependency:

```
function changeHelloToWorld(&$var) {
    // Responsibility has been shifted to the dependency
    if ($var === "Hello") {
        $var = "World";
    }
}

$word = "Hello";
changeHelloToWorld($word);
```

---

Here is another example using OOP:

```
<?php

class Human {
    private $hp = 0.5;

    function consume(Eatable $chunk) {
        // $this->chew($chunk);
        $chunk->unfoldEffectOn($this);
    }

    function incrementHealth() {
        $this->hp++;
    }
    function isHealthy() {}
    function getHungry() {}
    // ...
}

interface Eatable {
    public function unfoldEffectOn($body);
}

class Medicine implements Eatable {
    function unfoldEffectOn($human) {
        // The dependency is now in charge of the human.
        $human->incrementHealth();
        $this->depleted = true;
    }
}

$human = new Human();
$medicine = new Medicine();
if (!$human->isHealthy()) {
    $human->consume($medicine);   
}

var_dump($medicine);
var_dump($human);
```

<sub>*) Disclaimer: The real world human uses a message queue.</sub>

Comment: In the first two bits of code I'm having trouble identifying what/where is the call and what/where is the dependency.

Comment: @StayCool in the first example the change happens in the "main program", in the second snippet it happens within a function that is called.