# What is IoC in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Inversion of Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058/what-is-inversion-of-control)

I am not familiar with Inversion of Control (IoC). What is IoC and how can applications benefit from using IOC. How is it implemented in .NET with C#?

Comment: Please search for existing questions/answers before you post a new question - this topic has already been covered in some detail.

Comment: Inversion of Control (IoC) and dependency injection (DI) patterns are there to help remove dependencies from your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a set of classes that depend on eachother, it's difficult to replace some class for another (better/cheaper/faster) class that does the same job. In order to make your code more flexible, you can use **dependency injection**.

An easy to use DI framework for C# is Ninject. They have a very understandable tutorial about this subject.

Links:

http://ninject.org/learn

http://blog.andresays.org/2010/10/dependency-injection-with-ninject-and-asp-net-mvc/

Good luck!

Comment: Well said. Also, dependency injection improves testability.

Comment: Another IoC framework to look at is Castle Windsor: http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx#Samples_8

Comment: Your above links means `Dependency Injection` and not `Inversion of Control`. Correct ?

Comment: Try [Pure ID](https://github.com/DevTeam/Pure.DI) approach