# Dependency Injection in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is IOC in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759290/what-is-ioc-in-dotnet)

I am not familiar with Dependency Injection (DI). What is DI and how can applications benefit from using it? How is it implemented in .NET with C#?

Comment: There are a lot of articles returned by Google that cover this topic. Searching even on StackOverflow will return a host of marvelous information.

Comment: Ninject has a good and easy to read tutorial about this subject: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-By-Hand

Comment: Asked several times already, try to see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743951/help-with-dependency-injection-in-net

Comment: This is the exact same question you asked 25 min ago and just got closed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759290/what-is-ioc-in-dotnet

Comment: I found this video very useful, both explaining use and concept:
[Tekpub1 - Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control](http://tekpub.com/view/concepts/1) There are some more good videos at [tekpub](http://tekpub.com) worth having a look at.