# How to ensure that the filesystem and database are not accessed during unit tests in NUnit?

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing, filesystems, nunit

I'm looking for a way to cause unit tests to fail if they access the filesystem or database using NUnit and C#. I would preferably like to be able to set something up in a unit testing base class to prevent filesystem access on all child testing classes.

I currently need to disable the database service, run the unit tests, and check to see which ones fail in order to locate any tests that are accessing resources they aren't supposed to. I'd like to find a way to automate this process so that these tests will fail as soon as they are written.

Comment: That's a pretty cool idea. I think I will build on it on my next project. If you look at [.net trust levels](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754779.aspx) you will find that you could just run your unit tests in low trust mode and you will not only cause the tests to fail but DB/FileSystem (write) would fail in an exception!

Answer (score 0):

One way you could test the functionality of the system for particular scenarios (e.g. failing to access the filesystem) is by abstracting the portions of your code where you access the file system and then "plug" these into your classes where they're used via dependency injection.   By doing this, you can have tests where your mock file access objects throw specific errors and/or mimic success scenarios.  The follow post has some links on dependency injection that you may find useful

[Dependency Injection in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759528/dependency-injection-in-net)

You may also want to look into the SOLID principles for writing your code.