# What is Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control in Spring Framework?

Tags: spring, dependencies, controls, code-injection, inversion

"Dependency Injection" and "Inversion of Control" are often mentioned as the primary advantages of using the Spring framework for developing Web frameworks

Could anyone explain what it is in very simple terms with an example if possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Inversion of Control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058/what-is-inversion-of-control)

Comment: @SteveChambers its not duplicate, this question is asked in Springs Perspective. That question is in general prespective.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386896/how-field-injection-in-spring-boot-works-internally/57387256#57387256

Answer (score 302, accepted):

- Spring helps in the creation of loosely coupled applications because of **Dependency Injection**.
- In Spring, objects define their associations (dependencies) and do not worry about how they will get those **dependencies**. It is the responsibility of Spring to provide the required dependencies for creating objects.

**For example**: Suppose we have an object `Employee` and it has a dependency on object `Address`. We would define a bean corresponding to `Employee` that will define its dependency on object `Address`.

When Spring tries to create an `Employee` object, it will see that `Employee` has a dependency on `Address`, so it will first create the `Address` object (dependent object) and then inject it into the `Employee` object.

- Inversion of Control (**IoC**) and Dependency Injection (**DI**) are used interchangeably. IoC is achieved through DI. DI is the process of providing the dependencies and IoC is the end result of DI. (**Note:** DI is not the only way to achieve IoC. There are [other ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control#Implementation_techniques) as well.)
- By DI, the responsibility of creating objects is shifted from our application code to the Spring container; this phenomenon is called IoC.
- Dependency Injection can be done by setter injection or constructor injection.

Comment: I disagree. i don't think this is a clear explanation. Why can't you just instantiate "Address" inside "Employee" instead of getting a framework to crete it and inject it? A slightly more detailed example is called for.

Comment: @Boris Nobody said you can't instantiate your own objects. But the sole purpose of the answer was to demonstrate how you can achieve the same with DI. You can have both DI and objects instantiated by client code. This would still be called IOC, at least partially.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386896/how-field-injection-in-spring-boot-works-internally/57387256#57387256

Answer (score 38):

**I shall write down my simple understanding of this two terms:** (For quick understanding just read examples)

- **Dependency Injection(DI):**
  Dependency injection generally means **passing a dependent object as a parameter to a method, rather than having the method create the dependent object**.
  What it means in practice is that the method does not have a direct dependency on a particular implementation; any implementation that meets the requirements can be passed as a parameter.
  *With this implementation of objects defines their dependencies. And spring makes it available. 
  This leads to loosely coupled application development.*

  Quick Example:EMPLOYEE OBJECT WHEN CREATED,IT WILL AUTOMATICALLY CREATE ADDRESS OBJECT (if address is defines as dependency by Employee object)*.
- **Inversion of Control(IoC) Container:**
  This is common characteristic of frameworks, IoC **manages java objects** 
      - from instantiation to destruction through its BeanFactory. 
      - Java components that are instantiated by the IoC container are called beans, and the **IoC container manages a bean's scope, lifecycle events, and any AOP features** for which it has been configured and coded.
  *`QUICK EXAMPLE:Inversion of Control is about getting freedom, more flexibility, and less dependency. When you are using a desktop computer, you are slaved (or say, controlled). You have to sit before a screen and look at it. Using keyboard to type and using mouse to navigate. And a bad written software can slave you even more. If you replaced your desktop with a laptop, then you somewhat inverted control. You can easily take it and move around. So now you can control where you are with your computer, instead of computer controlling it`*. 
  By implementing Inversion of Control, a software/object consumer get more controls/options over the software/objects, instead of being controlled or having less options. 
  **Inversion of control as a design guideline serves the following purposes:**
  - There is a decoupling of the execution of a certain task from implementation.
  - Every module can focus on what it is designed for.
  - Modules make no assumptions about what other systems do but rely on their contracts.
  - Replacing modules has no side effect on other modules

I will keep things abstract here, you can visit following links for detail understanding of the topic.

[A good read with example](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-basic-constructor-injection.html)

[Detailed explanation](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/03/19/inversion-of-control-ioc-and-dependency-injection-di-patterns-in-spring-framework-and-related-interview-questions/)

Answer (score 16):

Inversion of control-
It means giving the control of creating and instantiating the spring beans to the Spring IOC container and the only work the developer does is configuring the beans in the spring xml file.

Dependency injection-

Consider a class Employee

```
class Employee { 
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private Address address;

   Employee() {
     id = 10;
     name="name";
     address = new Address();
   }


}
```

and consider class Address

```
class Address {
   private String street;
   private String city;

   Address() {
     street="test";
     city="test1";

  }
}
```

In the above code the address class values will be set only when the Employee class is instantiated, which is dependency of Address class on Employee class. And spring solves this problem using Dependency Injection concept by providing two ways to inject this dependency.

1. Setter injection

Setter method in Employee class which takes a reference of Address class

```
public void setAddress(Address addr) {
    this.address = addr;
}
```

2. Constructor injection

Constructor in Employee class which accepts Address

```
Employee(Address addr) {
      this.address = addr;
}
```

In this way the Address class values can be set independently using either setter/constructor injection.

Answer (score 14):

In Spring Objects are loosely coupled i.e., each class is independent of each other so that everything can be tested individually. But when using those classes, a class may be dependent on other classes which need to be instantiated first.

So, we tell spring that class A is dependent on class B. So, when creating bean(like class) for class A, it instantiates class B prior to that of class A and injects that in class A using setter or constructor DI methods. I.e., we are telling spring the dependency at run-time. This is DI.

As, we are assigning the responsibility of creating objects(beans), maintaining them and their aggregations to Spring instead of hard-coding it, we call it Inversion Of Control(IOC).

Answer (score 9):

**Inversion Of Control (IOC):**

**IoC** is a design pattern that describes inverting the flow of control in a system, so execution flow is not controlled by a central piece of code. This means that components should only depend on abstractions of other components and are not be responsible for handling the creation of dependent objects. Instead, object instances are supplied at runtime by an IoC container through Dependency Injection (DI).

IoC enables better software design that facilitates reuse, loose coupling, and easy testing of software components.

**Dependency Injection (DI):**

**DI** is a technique for passing dependencies into an object’s constructor. If the object has been loaded from the container, then its dependencies will be automatically supplied by the container. This allows you to consume a dependency without having to manually create an instance. This reduces coupling and gives you greater control over the lifetime of object instances.

[click to view more](https://timross.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/creating-a-simple-ioc-container/)

Answer (score 8):

Spring: Spring is “Inversion of Control” container for the Java Platform.

Inversion of Control (IoC): Inversion of Control (IoC) is an object-oriented programing practice whereby the object coupling is bounded at runtime by an "assembler" object and are typically not knowable at compile time using static analysis.

Dependency Injection (DI): "Dependency injection is a software design pattern that allows the removal of hard-coded dependencies and makes it possible to change them, whether at run-time or compile-time." -wiki.

Comment: How is this any simpler than what is already out there(which is where this answer is sourced from)? It doesn't account for the OP's request for simplicity, unless the double quotations around terminologies magically makes things simpler.

Answer (score 8):

In simple terms..

- IOC(Inversion of Control) is a concept that means: Instead of creating objects with the new operator,let the container do it for you.
- DI(Dependency injection) is way to inject the dependency of a framework component by the following ways of spring:

1. Contructor injection
2. Setter/Getter injection
3. field injection

Answer (score 6):

Inversion of Control is a generic design principle of software architecture that assists in creating reusable, modular software frameworks that are easy to maintain.

It is a design principle in which the Flow of Control is "received" from the generic-written library or reusable code.

To understand it better, lets see how we used to code in our earlier days of coding. In procedural/traditional languages, the business logic generally controls the flow of the application and "Calls" the generic or reusable code/functions. For example, in a simple Console application, my flow of control is controlled by my program's instructions, that may include the calls to some general reusable functions.

```
print ("Please enter your name:");
scan (&name);
print ("Please enter your DOB:");
scan (&dob);

//More print and scan statements
<Do Something Interesting>

//Call a Library function to find the age (common code)
print Age
```

In Contrast, with IoC, the Frameworks are the reusable code that "Calls" the business logic.

For example, in a windows based system, a framework will already be available to create UI elements like buttons, menus, windows and dialog boxes. When I write the business logic of my application, it would be framework's events that will call my business logic code (when an event is fired) and NOT the opposite.

Although, the framework's code is not aware of my business logic, it will still know how to call my code. This is achieved using events/delegates, callbacks etc. Here the Control of flow is "Inverted".

So, instead of depending the flow of control on statically bound objects, the flow depends upon the overall object graph and the relations between different objects.

Dependency Injection is a design pattern that implements IoC principle for resolving dependencies of objects.

In simpler words, when you are trying to write code, you will be creating and using different classes. One class (Class A) may use other classes (Class B and/or D). So, Class B and D are dependencies of class A.

A simple analogy will be a class Car. A car might depend on other classes like Engine, Tyres and more.

Dependency Injection suggests that instead of the Dependent classes (Class Car here) creating its dependencies (Class Engine and class Tyre), class should be injected with the concrete instance of the dependency.

Lets understand with a more practical example. Consider that you are writing your own TextEditor. Among other things, you can have a spellchecker that provides the user with a facility to check the typos in his text. A simple implementation of such a code can be:

```
Class TextEditor
{

    //Lot of rocket science to create the Editor goes here

    EnglishSpellChecker objSpellCheck;
    String text;

    public void TextEditor()

    {   

        objSpellCheck = new EnglishSpellChecker();

    }

    public ArrayList <typos> CheckSpellings()
    {

        //return Typos;

    }

}
```

At first sight, all looks rosy. The user will write some text. The developer will capture the text and call the CheckSpellings function and will find a list of Typos that he will show to the User.

Everything seems to work great until one fine day when one user starts writing French in the Editor.

To provide the support for more languages, we need to have more SpellCheckers. Probably French, German, Spanish etc.

Here, we have created a tightly-coupled code with "English"SpellChecker being tightly coupled with our TextEditor class, which means our TextEditor class is dependent on the EnglishSpellChecker or in other words EnglishSpellCheker is the dependency for TextEditor. We need to remove this dependency. Further, Our Text Editor needs a way to hold the concrete reference of any Spell Checker based on developer's discretion at run time.

So, as we saw in the introduction of DI, it suggests that the class should be injected with its dependencies. So, it should be the calling code's responsibility to inject all the dependencies to the called class/code. So we can restructure our code as

```
interface ISpellChecker
{

    Arraylist<typos> CheckSpelling(string Text);

}

Class EnglishSpellChecker : ISpellChecker

{

    public override Arraylist<typos> CheckSpelling(string Text)

    {

        //All Magic goes here.

    }

}



Class FrenchSpellChecker : ISpellChecker

{

    public override Arraylist<typos> CheckSpelling(string Text)

    {

        //All Magic goes here.

    }

}
```

In our example, the TextEditor class should receive the concrete instance of ISpellChecker type.

Now, the dependency can be injected in Constructor, a Public Property or a method.

Lets try to change our class using Constructor DI. The changed TextEditor class will look something like:

```
Class TextEditor

{

    ISpellChecker objSpellChecker;

    string Text;



    public void TextEditor(ISpellChecker objSC)

    {

        objSpellChecker = objSC;

    }



    public ArrayList <typos> CheckSpellings()

    {

        return objSpellChecker.CheckSpelling();

    }

}
```

So that the calling code, while creating the text editor can inject the appropriate SpellChecker Type to the instance of the TextEditor.

You can read the complete article [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/inversion-control-ioc-dependency-injection-di-amritpal-singh/)

Answer (score 4):

IOC is technique where you let someone else to create the object for you.
And the someone else in case of spring is IOC container.

Dependency Injection is a technique where one object supplies the dependency of another object.

Answer (score 3):

IOC stands for inversion of control and is a higher level concept that states that we invert the control of the creation of objects from the caller to the callee.

Without inversion of control, you are in charge of the creation of objects. In an inversion of control scenario a framework is in charge to create instances of a class.

Dependency injection is the method through which we can achieve inversion of control. In order for us to leave the control up to the framework or job we declare dependencies and the IOC container injects those dependencies in our class (i.e. the framework creates an instance for us and provides that to our class).

Now what are the advantages of this?

First of all the classes and their lifecycle will be managed by Spring. Spring completely manages the process from creation to destruction.

Secondly, you will get reduced coupling between classes. A class is not tightly coupled with an implementation of another class. If an implementation changes, or if you want to change the implementation of the injected interface you can do so easily without needing to change all the instances in your code base by hand.

Third, there is an increased cohesion between classes. High cohesion means keeping classes that are associated with one another together. Because we are injecting interfaces in other classes it is clear which classes are necessary for the calling class to operate.

Fourth, there is increased testability. Because we are using interfaces in the constructor we can easily swap out the implementation with a mock implementation

fifth, the use of JDK dynamic proxy to proxy objects. the JDK dynamic proxy requires interfaces to be used which is true, because we are injecting these interfaces. This proxy can then be used for Spring AOP, transaction handling, Spring data, Spring security and more

Answer (score 2):

The traditional way of getting address instance in Employee would be by creating a new instance of Address class.Spring creates all dependent object ton us hence we need not to worry about object.

So in Spring we just depend on the spring container which provide us with the dependency object.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring framework can be considered as a collection of sub-frameworks, also referred to as layers, such as Spring AOP, Spring ORM, Spring Web Flow, and Spring Web MVC. You can use any of these modules separately while constructing a Web application. The modules may also be grouped together to provide better functionalities in a web application.

Prior to penetrating down to Spring to container do remember that Spring provides two types of Containers namely as follows:

1. BeanFactory Container
2. ApplicationContext Container

The features of the Spring framework such as IoC, AOP, and transaction management, make it unique among the list of frameworks. Some of the most important features of the Spring framework are as follows:

1. IoC container
2. Data Access Framework
3. Spring MVC
4. Transaction Management
5. Spring Web Services
6. JDBC abstraction layer
7. Spring TestContext framework

Spring IoC Container is the core of Spring Framework. It creates the objects, configures and assembles their dependencies, manages their entire life cycle. The Container uses Dependency Injection(DI) to manage the components that make up the application. It gets the information about the objects from a configuration file(XML) or Java Code or Java Annotations and Java POJO class. These objects are called Beans. Since the Controlling of Java objects and their lifecycle is not done by the developers, hence the name Inversion Of Control.