# How we can get ride of the object using mockito

Tags: java, mockito, jmockit

I am trying to create a JUnit test for my method. I have a method

```
public a(int a, int b){
    a.setA(12);
    Injec inj = new Injec();
    inj.check();
    return (a*b);
}
```

I want to skip this section because it use HTTP request

```
Injec inj = new Injec();
inj.check();
```

I am using

```
when(Matchers.<Injec> anyObject().check()).thenReturn(null);
```

But it's giving me exception

Comment: Can you show the exception you are getting?

Comment: The argument you pass to `when` has to be a mock or a spy, not a matcher, so this won't work.  I wrote [an article about mocking object creation](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation) a few years ago on the Mockito wiki.  You may find it helpful for what you're trying  to achieve here.

Answer (score 3):

With Mockito, you won't be able to do that with your current code.

The problem is that the method `a` creates a new `Injec` object itself, directly by calling the default constructor. There's no way for Mockito to mock that new instance since it can't have any control over it.

As such, you need to refactor your code. There are a couples of possible solutions:

- pass the `Injec` instance as parameter to the `a` method. This way, you can mock the instance and give a mock to the method.
- inject the `Injec` instance into your class (with a constructor injection for example).

If you are using [JMockit](http://jmockit.org/), as noted by @Rogério, this is possible and you just need to add `@Mocked Injec` to your test class and the `Injec` instance will be mocked when it is created.

Comment: This is why `Inversion of Control` was invented : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403155/what-is-dependency-injection-and-inversion-of-control-in-spring-framework

Answer (score 0):

Using [JMockit](http://jmockit.org/) you can mock your `Injec` class as follows:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class MyTest
{
    private ClassToTest underTest;

    @Test
    public void testA(@Mocked Injec injec) {
        underTest.a(10, 20);

        // your assertions
    }
}
```