# What Is Spring IOC

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I am a newbie to Java world, coming from .Net. In the .net world we don't have so many options. I have some basic questions to help me get some more context.

Is the Spring Framework built on top of Java SE or Java EE?

Or are Java EE and Java SE Oracles products? Meaning Java SE is Oracle's implementation of Java?

What is Spring Framework built on? In other words, if I wanted to build a Spring like Framework would I start with Java SE as a base?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder, have you googled this question once, if not read this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403155/what-is-dependency-injection-and-inversion-of-control-in-spring-framework

Answer (score 2):

[Java SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition) (Standard Edition) and [Java EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) (Enterprise Edition) are not concrete *products*, they are *specifications*. There are implementations of these specifications available. Oracle's [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) (Java Development Kit) is an implementation of the Java SE specification.

Basically:

- Java SE = the Java programming language + the API of the standard library
- Java EE = extra APIs for enterprise computing

> Meaning Java SE is Oracle's implementation of Java?

No, Oracle's JDK is Oracle's implementation of Java SE (the specification).

Oracle also has a [Java EE SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html) which is an implementation of the Java EE specification, which includes the [GlassFish application server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish). There are other implementations of Java EE available, such as [WildFly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WildFly) (formerly JBoss), IBM's [WebSphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere) and Oracle's [WebLogic Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_WebLogic_Server).

[Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) is a library and framework built on Java SE, but it also supports some of the Java EE specification. You do not need a Java EE application server to use Spring.

About IoC (Inversion of Control), see: [What is Inversion of Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058/what-is-inversion-of-control)