# What is a bean, IoC and DI?

Tags: spring

I recently started learning spring, started reading and met with bean, ioc and di, I don’t quite understand how they work, I have ready-made spring programs I wrote myself, but how ioc worked there I don’t understand what the difference is normal class and what is it?) can you please explain with simple examples? I will be glad to all the answers, thank you very much

Comment: https://www.theserverside.com/feature/Meaning-of-inversion-of-control-in-Spring-and-Java-IoC-explained

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control in Spring Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403155/what-is-dependency-injection-and-inversion-of-control-in-spring-framework)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here goes a quick explanation, as you have already made an application. This is in the context of a Spring app, because those 3 concepts apply differently depending on the framework/context you're in.

IOC is Inversion Of Control. It means that the application won't manage it's lifecycle/flow of control itself. The framework (Spring) will. So you just tell the framework how you want (some) elements of your app to work together.

DI is dependency injection. It's a specific kind of IOC where the framework will manage the dependencies that an object uses (you can call dependency: a service).

Bean is an object managed by the Framework.

Here is part of a  applicationContext.xml:

```
 <beans>
  <bean id="foo" class="x.y.Foo">
      <constructor-arg ref="bar"/>
      <constructor-arg ref="baz"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="bar" class="x.y.Bar"/>
  <bean id="baz" class="x.y.Baz"/>

</beans>
```

It's going to use this file to instanciate the classes `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` (IoC), and **inject** both instance of `Bar` and `Baz` into `Foo` (DI). Those instance are thus `Beans`, managed by Spring (IoC).

If you ever need a bean (a service), you'll have to ask the Framework (using something like `context.getBean(foo)`): you're not supposed to do a `new Foo()` anywhere. Spring keeps an internal map of all these instances.

Again, it's in the context of a Spring app. These definitions will slightly differ if you're on a JEE application, for instance.

Comment: I am new to spring. Can you tell why it is good to delegate objects management to spring and use IoC

Comment: @Ali You can check this question which dwelves deeper into the advantages of IoC (whether it is spring, or any other framwork): https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/131446/what-is-inversion-of-control-and-when-should-i-use-it