# How Field Injection in Spring Boot works internally?

Tags: spring-boot

```
@Autowired
UserService userService;
```

What happens exactly inside `@Autowired annotation whether it uses **Constructor Injection** or **Setter Injection**. I know that it is field Injection.

I'm not asking How IOC or DI works, I'm asking How Field Injection in Spring Boot works internally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control in Spring Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403155/what-is-dependency-injection-and-inversion-of-control-in-spring-framework)

Comment: I'm asking how Field Injection works, not What is Ioc or DI? @NikolayShevchenko

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically field inject is a type of injection (obviously), so Spring injects dependency based on field type and maybe some annotations (like `@Qualifier`).

How does it work?

When Spring creates a bean, there is a special Bean Post Processor `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`

Each field marked with `@Autowired` is considered by spring as a dependency, so it must analyze these dependencies (by using reflection under the hood) and find a match from the application context for each field (by Type, qualifier if specified, etc.). Then it sets the value, right into the field, again by reflection.

I don't intend to start "holly-wars" here, but I'll just mention that I personally try to avoid using this type of injection because it effectively breaks encapsulation of dependencies, making the class with autowired fields non-unit testable.
For example if you have something like this:

```
  @Component
  class Foo {
     @Autowired 
     private Bar bar;
     public Foo() {} // no-arg construction that exists by default
  }

  @Component
  class Bar {
  }
```

Then when you create an instance of `Foo` by yourself (e.g. in unit-test) you have no clear way to supply the `Bar` dependency to `Foo` instance without relying on spring.

Constructor Injection solves this for example.

Comment: Yup, It's neither constructor nor setter injection, it's field injection, solves DI by reflection  under the hood