# Inversion Of Control: Is it more than Interfacing?

Tags: inversion-of-control

So I've been reading about it and every example I've come across, explain the concept with something like this:

**Original**:

```
A ---> B
```

**IoC**:

```
A ---> :I: ---> B ---> C , etc
```

Where `A` originally consumes something from `B` directly.
In **IoC**
`A` consumes an interface for which `B` is one of many possible implementations.

Is this really all there is to Inversion of Control?

Comment: As i understand it, IoC <==> callbacks, event handlers, such as that.

Comment: Possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058/what-is-inversion-of-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is like say Object Oriented is A:B. No IoC is not what you said, It has some purposes and one of a way to achieving its purposes is working like what you mentioned. 
If you see [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) it uses some basic patterns (actually more than what wiki mentioned):

> ```
> using a factory pattern
> using a service locator pattern
> using a constructor injection
> using a setter injection
> using an interface injection
> using a contextualized lookup
> ```

Also [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection) is one of a common concepts which involves when you doing IoC. I think if you read Martin Fowler's detailed article: "[Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)", you can understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not.  The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) says more on the subject than anyone here would want to say.