# Laravel: Avoid to create instance of a model with a constructor in the controller

Tags: php, laravel, oop, design-patterns, laravel-4

I'm following a course for Laravel 4 and the teacher did a code refactoring and introduced a magic method constructor in the controller

```
class UtentiController extends BaseController {

    protected $utente;

    public function __construct(Utenti $obj) {  
        $this->utente = $obj;
    }

    public function index() {
        $utenti = $this->utente->all();
        return View::make('utenti.index', ["utenti" => $utenti]);
    }

    public function show($username) {
        $utenti = $this->utente->whereusername($username)->first(); //select * from utenti where username = *;
        return View::make('utenti.singolo', ["utenti" => $utenti]);
    }

    public function create() {
        return View::make('utenti.create');
    }


    public function store() {
        if (! $this->utente->Valido( $input = Input::all() ) ) {
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->utente->messaggio);
        }

        $this->utente->save();
        return Redirect::route('utenti.index');
    }

}
```

Thanks to this code I don't have to create a new instance of the `Utenti` model every time:

```
protected $utente;
public function __construct(Utenti $obj) {

    $this->utente = $obj;

}
```

Now I can access the database with this simple approach:

```
$this->utente->all();
```

Whereas before, I had to do this:

```
$utente = new Utente;
$utente::all();
```

---

Does this type of technique have a name? (is it a pattern?).

My understanding is that every time the controller is invoked it automatically generates an instance of the User class (model) and applies an alias (reference) attribute `$utente`

Is that correct?

Also, here is the code for the `Utenti` model:

```
class Utenti extends Eloquent {

    public static $regole = [
        "utente" => "required",
        "password" => "required"
    ];

    public $messaggio;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['username','password'];

    protected $table = "utenti";

    public function Valido($data) { 
        $validazione = Validator::make($data,static::$regole);

        if ($validazione->passes()) return true;

        $this->messaggio = $validazione->messages();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called **dependency injection** or short DI. When creating a new instance of the Controller, Laravel checks the constructor for *type hinted* parameters (The ones that have a type defined like `__construct(Utenti $obj){`) If your controller has any of these Laravel tries to create an instance of the class and *injects* it into the constructor.

The reason why this is done is that it's becoming very clear what the dependencies of a class (in this case your controller) are. It gets especially interesting if you type hint an Interface instead of a concrete class. You then have to tell Laravel with a binding which implementation of the interface it should inject but you can also easily swap an implementation or mock it for unit testing.

Here are a few links where you can get more information:

- [Laravel docs IoC container](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc)
- [Method dependency injection in Laravel 5](http://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-method-injection)
- [StackOverflow - What is Inversion of Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3058/1903366)

Comment: in deph,with the pattern DI i can say to laravel: "hey: in this controller i need often the model Utente: so,when  you are called,create a instance of the Model Utente" with the attribute $utente i can use it like I have created a instance