# What is the main advantage of using an Ember Service class over other stereotypes?

Tags: ember.js

What benefits does an ember service class offer over other stereotypes like utils? I think it's related to DI, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: I don't think this question is a very good fit for the site, but to give you my opinion, it's all about dependency injection and inversion of control. You can read more about those [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058/what-is-inversion-of-control).

Comment: I know what DI is use it every day... my question pertains only to the new stereotype of Service classes released in ember recently.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking then. You wanted to know why one would use a service instead of a utility module and dependency injection _is_ the answer. Services use dependency injection, utility modules do not. That's really all there is to it.

Comment: I'd recommend to ask it on [the discussion board](http://discuss.emberjs.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary advantage is that you can use services from other Ember objects by using `Ember.inject.service()`.

For example, if you have a `user` service, you could do:

`// app/components/user.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  userService: Ember.inject.service('user'),
  displayName: Ember.computed('userService.model.{firstName,lastName}', function(){
    return [
      this.get('userService.model.firstName'),
      this.get('userService.model.lastName')
    ].compact().join(' '); 
  }),
  avatarUrl: Ember.computed.readOnly('userService.model.avatarUrl'),
});`