# How to remove dependency between two classes?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

for example:

```
public class A {}

public class B
{
    public void test()
    {
        A obj = A();
    }
}
```

I just looking for best way to remove dependency between class `A` and `B`, Or which design pattern is best suited for this if more classes added at sub classes level?

Comment: Program into an interface not an implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Receive an instance of `A` in the constructor. Even better is to have `A` inherit some interface and receive that interface in the constructor.

```
public interface IA {}
public class A : IA {}

public class B 
{
    public IA AInstance { get; set; }
    public B (IA a)
    {
        AInstance = a;
    }

    public void test()
    {
        /* do something with `AInstance` */
    }
}
```

Look into the concepts of [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control):

1. [What is dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/130794/6400526)
2. [What is Inversion of Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3058/6400526)

And wrap it all under the [SOLID principals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

---

If you can't get `IA` as a dependency but need to create a new instance of it in your `B` class then use the Factory design pattern and let `B` depend on some instance of `ISomeFactory`

Comment: Thanks - but I think here we need to use new keyword inside B class. and again there have dependent on each other.

Comment: thanks - I also think same but is there any other way in which we avoid to use new  keyword inside B.

Comment: @ROOMY - If you have to instanciate a `B` class in `A` then I think rethink the design to see if it is really needed and if still then look into the `Factory` design pattern - and have a dependency on some `ISomeFactory`

Comment: Awesome I got a badge from the reference to my documentation on the Factory Pattern!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you'd use IoC as design pattern. It removes the dependency of your classes and makes it possible to mock your objects while unit testing

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973811.aspx

Comment: Dependency Injection should be enough

Comment: Well he asked for a design pattern ;)

Comment: Then we should tutor him design patterns should only be used when you have a problem they solve. Why guide someone to IoC when this is overkill? What he needs is design principles. in this case single responsibility and dependency inversion.