# How can in run my spring boot application with "java -cp example.jar com.example.MyMainClass"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classloader, bootclasspath

I tried to change the Spring Boot class loader.. but it is not working, only print this message:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.MyMainClass

I have tried this solution: https://github.com/dkublik/spring-boot-loader-play

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring Boot 2.1.5.RELEASE, the following should work:

```
java -cp "yourfile.jar" org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

Please, note that the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` repackages the original jar file at maven's `package` build phase, which results in a jar with a different internal file structure. In this new/repackaged jar, you can find the classes from your project inside `BOOT-INF/classes/`, which differs from the original jar, where you find them in the first level of the file structure. The plugin keeps the original jar file as `yourfile.jar.original` inside the `target` folder.

Also, i suggest to take a look at the file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` inside the repackaged jar, which reflects the description above. If you open this file you should see something similar to the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: yourproject
Implementation-Version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Start-Class: com.example.MyMainClass
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Build-Jdk-Spec: 1.8
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.1.5.RELEASE
Created-By: Maven Archiver 3.4.0
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

Please, note that the value of the `Main-Class` header from repackaged jars will always be `org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher`, defining this as the entry point of your jar. Later on, Spring will look for the `Start-Class` header, thus loading your project through [IoC (Inversion of Control)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058/what-is-inversion-of-control).

For more info:

[Packaging Programs in JAR Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html)

[Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html)

[Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/inversion-control-and-dependency-injection-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

## Try to create a `fat jar`. This way you can run your `application with`

```
java -cp example.jar

<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
      <execution>
       <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
         </goals>
         </execution>
        </executions>
       <configuration>
          <finalName>example</finalName>
      </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Answer (score -2):

Wouldn't:

`java -jar application.jar`

work for you?