# IoC - Where does Control "Invert" To? (Where does it go?)

Tags: c#, .net, oop, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Basic theory question alert!

Its about IoC.

I was reading about IoC, and realized how i am not fully comfortable about the exact meaning of the term.

Then, I came across a specific Answer about IoC, which made me realize, that IoC is not just about control/dependency between classes, it is a much more general term: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3108/976537

> "instead of the computer accepting user input in a fixed order, the user controls the order in which the data is entered"

Interesting. Now i am a lot more comfortable with the term.

Then i was reading [this article about IoC and achieving it via basic DI](http://joelabrahamsson.com/inversion-of-control-an-introduction-with-examples-in-net/), which i am very comfortable with, implement all the time, know the benefits of etc.

But, in the scenario below, going from figure 1 to figure 2, we take control away from OrderService. OrderServices only knows about an abstraction now, great. Plenty benefits.
[image]

EDIT: The code (from the article) in Figure 1, above, is:

```
public class OrderService
{
    public void AcceptOrder(Order order)
    {
        new OrderDatabase().SaveOrder(order);
    }
}
```

Then, after IoC & DI is implemented in Figure 2 above, the code is:

```
public class OrderService
{
    private IOrderSaver orderSaver;

    public OrderService(IOrderSaver orderSaver)
    {
        this.orderSaver = orderSaver;
    }

    public void AcceptOrder(Order order)
    {
        orderSaver.SaveOrder(order);
    }
}
```

My question is, where is control considered to have gone?

Has control considered to be been shifted to:

1 - The interface? (my feeling is that this is unlikely)

2 - The IOC container used to wire up for DI at runtime? (my feeling is this one is a maybe)

3 - Or OrderDatabase (i feel this is the most likely answer)

SO - where has control been inverted to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the following code

```
public class OrderService {
    public void AcceptOrder(Order order) {

        //...Domain logic such as validation

        //then save order
        new OrderDatabase().SaveOrder(order);
    }
}
```

`OrderService` should not be responsible for creating `OrderDatabase`, which violates Single Responsibility Principle (SRP). It is tightly coupling itself to implementation concerns which violates Separation of Concerns (SoC).

By inverting the control that `OrderService` has in creating the dependency, 
 it explicitly depends on an abstraction of the desired functionality in the refactored version

```
public class OrderService {
    private readonly IOrderSaver orderSaver;

    public OrderService(IOrderSaver orderSaver) {
        this.orderSaver = orderSaver;
    }

    public void AcceptOrder(Order order) {

        //...Domain logic such as validation

        //then save order
        orderSaver.SaveOrder(order);
    }
}
```

delegating/inverting that control of creating the dependency to the consumer of the `OrderService` (*what ever is responsible for creating and using the `OrderService`*)

which could be a DI/IoC container or via [pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) (*Dependency Injection without a DI Container*)

Whether DI via container or pure DI does not matter as they will be considered implementation details which is of no concern to the target class, in this case `OrderService`.

Comment: Thank you. The key information i was looking for you provided with this: "delegating/inverting that control of creating the dependency to the consumer of the OrderService (what ever is responsible for creating and using the OrderService)

which could be a DI/IoC container or via pure DI"

Comment: @fourbeatcoder hopefully this clears up the confusion you had before.