# Can I completely omit a private method in a tested public method using JUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit4

I have a problem with one test.

Let's say, there was a method like this:

```
public Item doSomething(Some parameters) {
    Item item = someMethodDoingSomethingWithParameters(parameters)
    return item;
}
```

but then I have introduced new functionality, sending notifications.

```
public Item doSomething(List<Some> parameters) {
    Item item = someMethodDoingSomethingWithParameters(parameters)
    sendNotificationToItemOwners(parameters);
    return item;
}
```

this `sendNotificationToItemOwners(List<Some> parameters)` method looks like this:

```
private void sendNotificationToOwners(parameters) {
    parameters.stream().forEach(parameter -> notificationService.sendNotification(paremeter.getOwnerEmail());
}
```

I don't want to test a lambda, and I don't want to test the `NotificationService` cause it is allready well tested.

The code I wrote is a *very* simplified version of my original code. The addition of this new `sendNotificationToOwners()` method gives me headaches, the test is failing, I am trying to mock some objects required, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Can I **completely** omit this method in a test? It would be wonderful if it would be possible..

Comment: no u cannot. but it is not hard to mock notificationService. Put your Class under Test and Your Test class.

Comment: Indeed, you can't omit it (at least not without finding a framework that would do bytecode modification, which would not be a route you'd want to take), but mocking the service is idiomatic and should be easy.

Comment: This new method is part of the *desired behavior* of your unit under test. Therefore it should be tested tough.  But as the others pointed out you should mock the `notificationService` and verify that its method `sendNotification()` is called with each entry of the `parameters` collection.

Comment: No. In Unit Test you test your public API and assert for behavior you expect. Since it invokes a private method you do want to test that interaction by mocking `notificationService`. If the `lamda` code is huge, follow Single Responsibility Principle, and refactor it to it's own `class`.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to test a lambda,

Lambda expressions aren't exempt from unit testing. I'd say it's a pretty dangerous way of looking at them.

> and I don't want to test the `NotificationService` cause it is already well tested.

Mock it then and allow an instance to be injected into the class under test via a constructor or a factory method (or annotate the field if you're using a dependency injection framework). Your private lambda will still execute but won't actually use the other, possibly complex class. If the class being tested here doesn't already allow an instance of `NotificationService` to be provided upon creation, refactor it so that [inversion of control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3058/1407656) can be achieved.

> Can I completely omit this method in a test? It would be wonderful if it would be possible..

Technically, instead of injecting a `NotificationService` reference, you could extract the private method `sendNotificationToOwners` to a separate class and inject/mock that. However, that class would just iterate over the parameters and invoke `NotificationService`. Seems like a bit of an overkill. My preference would be to inject `NotificationService` and just let the lambda run and invoke `sendNotification` on a mock/spy object. That would also allow you to test that `NotificationService` has been called for each parameter.