# How Inversion of Control is achieved in TESTNG. Is Test Annotation in testng example of IOC?

Tags: testing, automation, frameworks, testng, inversion-of-control

How Inversion of Control is achieved in TESTNG. Is Test Annotation in testng example of IOC ?

Answer (score 0):

TestNG is the testing framework, IOC is a pattern. Why do you need to apply this pattern to your test? What are you trying to solve? You should understand your problem and find out a solution to resolve it.You can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058/what-is-inversion-of-control#:%7E:text=Inversion%20of%20Control%20(IoC)%20means,instance%20creating%20instances%20of%20dependencies.). All design patterns are heuristics, and heuristic means a fallible to solving a problem.

Comment: Firstly you should understand that IOC is not a pattern. It is a principle. Secondly , all frameworks will implicitly implement the IOC principle. I wanted to know in TestNG framework where that happens. Hope you get a clarity.