# Should I use DbContext in controller or rather use it in model or service called from coltroller? MVC ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to check if some data from the input form is contained in DbContext. Should I check it in controller or controller should just call method from model or service to which will do it?

Comment: This question welcomes opinionated answers, but I would personally say, that your controller can very easily get cluttered and unmanageable, if you do everything in it, so I would call a service-method in a service-class, that contains the logic.

Comment: "It depends" =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would be cleaner if there be a mediator called "Services". a class whose duty is to collect data from your DB and provide that to your application layer which in your case is your controller, notice just that has accessibility to your context. Also, you can take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058/what-is-inversion-of-control) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection)
to have the cleanest code

Comment: I see what you mean, but what if you need to include users at one point. And at another point you want to include users and usersHistory. That becomes a method for each and one of them? Isn't it better to return an IQuearyAble?