# Unable to mock AmazonS3 instance in Java

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have been trying to test my code which internally calls Amazons3.listObjects(), but i am struggling with mocking the Amazons3 class. Can some one please let me know the right way to do it?

here is the code
Processor.class

```
 AmazonS3 s3 = getS3Build();

 final List<String> flagFiles = s3.listObjectsV2(dataBucket, flagFolder)


public AmazonS3 getS3Build() {
    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(US_EAST_1).build();
  }
```

Test.class

```
Mockito.when(processor.getS3Build()).thenReturn(s3);

Mockito.when(s3.listObjectsV2(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(listObjectsV2Result);
```

Error occuring at s3.listObjectsV2

```
Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
```

I don't understand why its trying to call the actual listObjectsV2 when i have already mocked the class.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
Mockito.when(processor.getS3Build()).thenReturn(s3);

Mockito.when(s3.listObjectsV2(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(listObjectsV2Result);
```

At least the way you're showing it here the issue is that your test subject (`processor`) seems to be an already constructed Object. Setting the `Amazon s3` member variable inline like that will cause that line of code to execute as soon as the Object is constructed.

So by the time you're mocking `getS3Build` it's already been called.

There are several different ways to reorganize your code to change this up to make it more testable:

- you could make the `Amazon s3` variable initialized after Object construction with an explicit `initialize` method
- you could use Inversion of Control to inject the `Amazon s3` variable into the `Processor.class`
- you could use reflection or a explicit setter method to give you the flexibility to change the `Amazon s3` member variable after Object construction

## Helpful References

- IoC explained: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3140/8876886