# How do I get secrets.json or azure secrets in an Authorization filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have `secrets.json` and Azure KeyVault setup in my application exactly as the MS tutorial suggest. I also have an authorization filter. All is working fine.

In a controller, I pass `IConfiguration` in and do:

```
_config["KEY"]
```

to access a value from my secrets.

How do I access these values in the custom `AuthorizationFilter`? It will not let me pass in attributes as I typically would.

In fact, if I could actually get my `DbContext` in the filter, I wouldn't need to access the config, but I can't pass that in either.

I want to either replace the string with a value from my vault or pull in the `DbContext` I created in `Program.cs`:

```
// Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options => Options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

// In my filter...
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DBContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("{STRING}");
    var dbContext = new DBContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have to use httpContext services

```
 public class TestFilter : AuthorizeFilter
    {
        public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var config = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IConfiguration>();
            var db = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<DBContext>();
            return base.OnAuthorizationAsync(context);
        }
    }
```

So you will use DI on Authorization request. I would assume that .net core would create singleton instance of filter this is why constructor injections wont work.

Comment: Just for clarification of my understanding, DI means Direct Injection, yes?

Comment: @flashsplat dependency injection/Inversion of control its where you dont create services but inject them and framework take care of creating and destructing them

Comment: @flashsplat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058/what-is-inversion-of-control