# What are the prerequisites for learning Spring framework & Cassandra database?

Tags: java, spring, database, cassandra, nosql

I am new to Spring framework. I have done core Java. I want to know what prerequisites are required to start learning Spring Framework?

Also I am completely new to world of databases. Should Straight away start with Cassandra database to learn or are there any prerequisites to complete before that?

Above two questions are not related to each other. Both have different standalone context.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know what prerequisites are required to start learning
> Spring Framework?

The first and obvious thing I can suggest to you is to:

1. Visit the [Spring](https://spring.io/) project web site
2. Take a course on **Udemy** or see some free courses on **Youtube**.

If you want to go deeply in the subject, I can suggest the following path:

1. Understand deeply the *[Inversion Of Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058/what-is-inversion-of-control)* (IoC) and *[Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection)* (DI) pattern. You can do DI without Spring.
2. Understand how **Spring** helps you implements IoC and DI
3. Understand how **Spring** [projects](https://spring.io/projects) are organized (difference between **Spring** and **Spring Boot**)
4. Read very carefully the [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.26-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/) documentation available of the web site
5. Do all the quick [tutorials](https://spring.io/quickstart) available on **Spring** web site

For Cassandra:

> Also I am completely new to world of databases. Should Straight away
> start with Cassandra database to learn or are there any prerequisites
> to complete before that?

1. Read on Database concept, start with relational database such as [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/)
2. Take a course on **Udemy** or a free course on **Youtube**.
3. Read the [documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/) of the web site
4. Read on [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) paradigm

My last advice is: **Open and read StackOverflow everyday, it is an endless source of knowledge**

Answer (score 0):

If you already know Java then you can start learning about Spring immediately. The whole idea with Spring is that it makes it easier to build Java applications.

The [Spring.io](https://spring.io/) website is a very good resource and a good place to start, particularly the [Spring Academy](https://spring.academy/courses) for free hands-on courses.

DataStax run free workshops every week where you can learn about Cassandra and how to build apps live with hands-on exercises. You don't need to know Cassandra to attend and everything you need for the workshop is provided free.

There are three featured workshops listed on [datastax.com/workshops](https://www.datastax.com/workshops) you can do now:

- [Intro to Cassandra for Developers](https://www.datastax.com/workshops/introduction-to-cassandra-for-developers)
- [Build an eCommerce Website with Spring Boot + Cassandra](https://www.datastax.com/workshops/build-an-ecommerce-website-with-spring-boot-and-a-nosql-db)
- [Build scalable Microservices with Spring Boot + Cassandra](https://www.datastax.com/workshops/build-scalable-api-based-microservices-with-spring-boot-and-cassandra)

Again, you do NOT need to know about Cassandra to do these workshops because everything you need to know will be discussed and covered.

If you want to spend a bit more time learning about Cassandra, there are hands-on tutorials at [datastax.com/dev](https://www.datastax.com/dev) and full-blown courses at [DataStax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com/) which are all free. Cheers!

Comment: How about using Cassandra docs?

Comment: They're on the official Apache website -- https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/. 