# What are bad sides of using Symfony's ServiceLocator?

Tags: php, symfony, service-locator

The college told me that sometimes I overuse ServiceLocator in Symfony 5.4 project.
I never considered that possibility. Everything seems straightforward => you get services from the container as you usually do. Instead of using a factory, you use a service locator and you do not care about dependencies.

So, am I right here, or it is possible to overuse ServiceLocator in Symfony?
If yes please advice when it is ok to use it?

Comment: This is probably not the best place for these sorts of opinion based questions.  [Symfony Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/symfony/new/) might be a better spot. You might also consider updating your question with a specific example of one of your service locators.  In general locators should be used when you don't know in advance exactly which service you need.  Should be rare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [inversion of control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3140/814253) through [dependency injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html).
Main advantages of this approach (in no specific order and maybe I'm forgetting some of them)

- you're not tied to the whole container
- you have a clear overview of all dependency
- you can write code over interfaces instead of concrete implementations
- your classes become more testable

So if you're using service locator everywhere for your dependencies, I agree that you're overusing it

Comment: Thanks for answer. However I have question for each of your points. :) Please answer shortly if you have time: In symfony you are definitely tied to a container. Everything is in container; You must specify your dependencies because you are using ServiceSubscriberInterface; Ok. code over interfaces I got that; By now I can test any of that code. So I still do not see some big problem here. I am using it when I have to decide between multiple steps, depending on some incoming parameter.